# Application-defined or object defined error with 2 long variables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to using VBA macros and I can't seem to figure this problem out.

I am trying to create a macro to do an advanced filter. I want the macro to filter the results in columns A:E against a list of numbers in column N. I am wanting the macro to be able to vary the list range by finding the last occupied row in column E, which I have assigned to the variable BlankRowinE. I then assign the resulting range of cells to the range variable ListRange.

This part of my code appears to work. However when I try to modify the criteria range in the advanced filter so that it will use the range N1: the last occupied cell in column N, I get an Application-defined or object-defined error.

I'm sure I'm making some obvious mistake due to my inexperience but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Advance_Filter()

Advance_Filter Macro

Dim LastBlankRowE As Long
Dim ListRange As Range


LastBlankRowE = Worksheets("GWN parts").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(LastBlankRowE, 5).Select
Set ListRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveCell)

Range("A2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ListRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("N1", Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(x1Up).Row), Unique:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the only issue but change `Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(x1Up).Row` to just be `Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp)`.  Note: that `x1Up` needs to be `xlUp` as well as getting rid of the `.Row`.  (This is weird, this is the second question in 24 hours where the user has used `x1` instead of `xl`, and that other question had a `.Column` at the end when they shouldn't have had it.)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't fix it but I appreciate the syntax help. I should have included this above, but the filter works if I set the criteria to a range of cells such as Range("N1", "N22")

Comment: Specify `Option Explicit`. That `x1` typo should have been a compiler error.

Comment: If `ListRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= Range("N1", "N22"), Unique:=False` (with no other changes to your code) works, then using `ListRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= Range("N1", Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp)), Unique:=False` should have worked too.